# Ejercicio sobre eventos

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación que me saque la hora, minutos y segundos y los introduzca dentro de un  con el método innerHTML.

Por alguna razón la aplicación no me funciona, creo que el problema está en cuando intento introducir variables dentro del innerHTML.

Espero sus respuestas,

gracias.

EDITO: Si quiero que se me actulice automáticamente la hora que introduzco en el div cada 500 milisegundos, ¿Cómo utilizaría la función setTimeout()?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>


    <script>


        function obtenerHora(){

            var d= new Date();

            var hora=d.getHours();
            var minutos= d.getMinutes();
            var segundos=d.getSeconds();

        } 

        window.onload=function(){

            document.getElementById("reloj").innerHTML=hora+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="reloj" style="width:15rem;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En ningun momento estas llamando a obtenerHora por lo que las variables no existen.

Answer (score 5):

Tienes dos problemas.  Primero, las variables hora, minutos y segundos son locales a la funcion `obtenerHora` por lo que no estan definidas fuera de ella.  Segundo, necesitas llamar a dicha funcion en algun momento, de otra forma el codigo nunca se ejecutara.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>


    <script>


        function obtenerHora(){

            var d= new Date();

            var hora=d.getHours();
            var minutos= d.getMinutes();
            var segundos=d.getSeconds();
            document.getElementById("reloj").innerHTML=hora+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
        } 

        window.onload=function(){
            obtenerHora();
            
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="reloj" style="width:15rem;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta. Si quisiera que el reloj se actualizase automáticamente, acaso no valdría con introducir: setTimeout(obtenerHora(),500); dentro del window.onload?

Comment: Seria: setInterval(() => obtenerHora(), 500); el segundo parametro son los ms, queremos que el reloj se refresque cada medio segundo

Comment: De hecho, creo que la funcion que buscas seria `setInterval()`

Answer (score 4):

```html
<form>
<p id='reloj'></p>

<script>


    function obtenerHora(){

        var d= new Date();

        var hora=d.getHours();
        var minutos= d.getMinutes();
        var segundos=d.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById("reloj").innerHTML=hora+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
    } 

    window.onload=function(){
        obtenerHora();

    }

//setInvertal(() => obtenerHora(), 500);
setInterval(function(){ obtenerHora() }, 500);

</script>
</form>
```

```
<script>


    function obtenerHora(){

        var d= new Date();

        var hora=d.getHours();
        var minutos= d.getMinutes();
        var segundos=d.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById("reloj").innerHTML=hora+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
    } 

    window.onload=function(){
        obtenerHora();

    }

setInvertal(() => obtenerHora(), 500);

</script>
```

El set interval es una funcion que ejecuta otra funcion cada cierta cantidad de tiempo